# fix - warning "Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments" when running hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop

When I submit hadoop job It always said

`WARN [JobClient] Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same`

How can I fix this? 
I am using CDH 4.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like below driver code to start your MapReduce job to get rid of warning (although it doesn't do any harm):

```
public class MyClass extends Configured implements Tool {
   public int run(String [] args) throws IOException {
     JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), MyClass.class);
     // run the job here.
     return 0;
   }

   public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
      int status = ToolRunner.run(new MyClass(), args); // calls your run() method.
      System.exit(status);
   }
}
```